# When would the verb 'start' be used without an object?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I always thought the verb 'start' needed an object, for example 'I started writing a letter', or 'she started the car', but recently I read the below in a novel (THE WITCH OF BLACKBIRD POND)..

> Kit started. Had he guessed? There was no one who could possibly have
> told him. She had kept her secret even from the Captain's wife.

What does that first sentence mean? What did she 'start' doing?

Comment: Different sense of "start" -- reacted with surprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are just ***loads and loads*** of intransitive uses of *start* that mean something like to jump or ***startle***. Indeed, that’s the oldest use of the verb, which is why they’re all under Branch I below.

Here are just a few of them, courtesy of the OED.

> #### I. To (cause to) make a sudden movement, and related senses.
>
> 1. *intransitive*. To leap, jump; to caper, cavort; (also) to leap or spring upon a horse. Also *figurative*. *Obsolete*.
> 2. a. *intransitive*. To move with a bound or sudden impulse from a position of rest or repose; (also) to come suddenly *from* or *out of* a place of concealment.
>    c. *intransitive*. To rise suddenly *on* or *upon*, or (in later use esp.) *to*, one's feet (formerly also occasionally with *legs*); to stand up.

> 4. a. *intransitive*. Of an inanimate object or substance, esp. a liquid: to issue suddenly and with force; to fly, flow, or be projected by a sudden impulse. Frequently with *out, out of, from*.

> 6. a.  (a) *intransitive*. To make a sudden movement, esp. of part of one's body, as to avoid a blow or perceived threat; to flinch or recoil from something in alarm or repugnance. Chiefly with *from* or with adverbs (as *aback, aside, away, back*, etc.). Also with the part of the body as subject.
>    (b) *intransitive*. Of a horse: to shy; to swerve suddenly from its course in fright or alarm; to bolt (also with adverbs, as *aside, astray*, etc.).
> 7. a. *Hunting* 
>    (b) *intransitive*. Of an animal: to emerge, esp. suddenly, from its lair or place of refuge. Also with *up*.
> 8. a. *intransitive*. To undergo a sudden involuntary movement of the body, resulting from surprise, fright, sudden pain, etc.; (sometimes without implication of actual movement) to feel startled or momentarily perturbed, as at a sudden realization.
> 9. a. (a) *intransitive*. To awake abruptly *out of* (also *from*, †*out*) sleep, a daze, etc.; to come *awake* with a start.
>    b. *intransitive*. To come suddenly, or with a start, *into* (formerly †*in*) a particular state or condition; to fly *into* a rage, burst *into* life, etc.; (also) to go suddenly *out of* one's wits. Formerly also with †*off*. Now *rare* (in later use coloured by senses in branch II.).

There are ***many*** more than just these that I’ve selected here.

The Branch II senses that you’re thinking of mean to begin, but the Branch I senses are much much older, beginning way back in Old English when we used 3-digit years. :) The Branch II senses started in Early Modern English, and those are probably the only ones you are thinking of.  Those don’t apply here.

Comment: And note that a transitive form doesn't generally *require* an object, it just *allows* one.

Comment: @HotLicks Here’s a related transitive sense’s citation from a 2004 work: *I was **started** from my sleep by the sound of loud and very hurried steps in the hall.*

Comment: How is that use transitive?

Comment: @HotLicks Because it's passive, and all passives are transitive by definition. It means: *The sound and steps started me from my sleep.* When you passivize, you exchange subject and object, and you can do that only with transitive verbs because otherwise there is no object to swap places with the subject. It's just like how transitive *The ball hit me* becomes *I was hit by the ball* in the passive.

Comment: @tchrist: Thank you very much for your last comment. I had always been wondering why Merriam-Webster lists certain verbs as transitive (_a proposal assailed by critics_) when there seems to be no _sense of transitivity_ involved, if you will. Could you reference a source that talks about this point a bit further? Thanking you in advance.

Comment: @BillJ: I would like to hear from you about _tchrist's comment_ (all passives are transitive) at this point.

Comment: @user405662 There *assail* is the transitive verb. The critics assailed the proposal. Swap subject and object to get a proposal assailed by critics.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with your assertion that all passives are transitives by definition. They are actually intransitive. The effect of switching from the active to the passive is to switch from a transitive clause to an intransitive one. (@user405662)

Comment: @BillJ I meant that all passives were originally a transitive verb that had had its subject and object switched around.  It isn't "still" transitive while expressed passively, but you can usually recover the active transitive form without much trouble.

Comment: @tchrist: _There assail is the transitive verb_ and _It isn't "still" transitive while expressed passively_ ——these seem to be contradictory statements.

Comment: @user405662 All passive constructions are predicated upon a transitive verb being placed into its past participle inflection and this past participle then applied to the original subject of that transitive verb, with or without whiz-deletion, and with or without the prepositional phrase using *by* and the original object. The OED’s example citation of *start* used transitively clearly does this. *“I was **started** from my sleep **by** the sound of loud and very hurried steps in the hall.”* is merely the result of passivizing active *“The **sound and steps started me** from my sleep”*.

Comment: The point here is that in the passive _I was started from my sleep by the sound of loud and very hurried steps in the hall_, "started" is used intransitively and thus the clause is intransitive.